# Spring Boot Actuator failing to start up with error creating mbeamexporter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-boot

I have an spring boot application that is failing to startup after a redeploy of the application.  The error appears to be cause by failure to create mbeanExporter.

I have also include the following line in the property file hoping to prevent the error on startup.

```
endpoints.jmx.domain=app_dcs_consumerappointmentnotification
```

I have uninstalled and restarted the JVM several times.  Sometimes after a restart of the JVM the error disappears.

```
2014/10/07 17:09:54.727 ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/context/annotation/MBeanExportConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [(inner bean)#3449a0f0] with key 'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#1'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#1,type=ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120) ~[spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) ~[spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:89) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:51) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5444) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1074) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [(inner bean)#3449a0f0] with key 'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#1'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#1,type=ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:609) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:534) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:416) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#1,type=ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:662) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:599) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you don't stop your application properly and those MBeans hasn't been unregistered from JMX.

Try to use:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport(registration = RegistrationPolicy.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

Since we see an issue with Spring Integration MBean.

Comment: Since he says this happens "Sometimes" he should really get to the root cause as to why, sometimes, there's already an MBean with that object name. He also says "redeploy", which implies to me that the old instance is still running.

Comment: How would I check to see if the old mbeans are still running after undeploy?  Also should I set this property endpoints.jmx.uniqueNames=true?

Comment: I'm getting the same error in a different project without Spring Boot Actuator.